# Forloops Assignment

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I am a grade 11 student that needs help with a forloop assignment assigned by my teacher.

The problem with the code is that the output posts, but it appears only for a few milliseconds before vanishing.

```js
function loops1() {
  var inputV = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  var inputINT = parseInt(inputV);
  var show = "";
  try {
    if (inputV == "") throw "is empty";
    if (isNaN(inputV)) throw 'must be a number';
  } catch (err) {
    alert("Input field " + err);
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= inputINT; i++) {
    show += i + '<br>';
  }
  document.getElementById('showN').innerHTML = 'Numbers in order from 1 to n:' + '<br>' + show;
}

function loops2() {
  var inputV = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  var inputINT = parseInt(inputV);
  var sum = 0;
  try {
    if (inputV == "") throw "is empty";
    if (isNaN(inputV)) throw 'must be a number';
  } catch (err) {
    alert("Input field " + err);
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= inputINT; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
  document.getElementById('showN').innerHTML = 'Sum of numbers from 1 to n:' + '<br>' + sum;
}

function loops3() {
  var inputV = document.getElementById('input3').value;
  var inputINT = parseInt(inputV);
  var sumE = 0;
  try {
    if (inputV == "") throw "is empty";
    if (isNaN(inputV)) throw 'must be a number';
  } catch (err) {
    alert("Input field " + err);
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= inputINT; i++) {
    if ((i % 2) == 0) sumE += i;
  }
  document.getElementById('showN').innerHTML = 'Sum of even numbers from 1 to n:' + '<br>' + sumE;
}

function loops4() {
  var inputV = document.getElementById('input4').value;
  var inputINT = parseInt(inputV);
  var factorial = 1;
  try {
    if (inputV == "") throw "is empty";
    if (isNaN(inputV)) throw 'must be a number';
  } catch (err) {
    alert("Input field " + err);
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= inputINT; i++) {
    factorial = factorial * i;
  }
  document.getElementById('showN').innerHTML = 'Factorial of n:' + '<br>' + factorial;
}

function loops5() {
  var sports = ["Cricket", "Volleyball", "Basketball", "Hockey", "Soccer", "Football"];
  var sportsD = "";
  var lenA = sports.length
  for (var i = 0; i < lenA; i++) {
    sportsD += sports[i] + '<br>';
  }
  document.getElementById('showN').innerHTML = 'List of Sports:' + '<br>' + sportsD;
}
```

```html
<h1>LOOPS</h1>
<form>
  Write all numbers between 0 and input<br>
  <input type='text' id='input1' placeholder='enter number'><br>
  <button onclick='loops1()' type='submit'>Submit</button><br><br> Write sum of numbers 1 to input<br>
  <input type='text' id='input2' placeholder='enter number'><br>
  <button onclick='loops2()' type='submit'>Submit</button><br><br> Write sum of even numbers from 1 to input<br>
  <input type='text' id='input3' placeholder='enter number'><br>
  <button type='submit' onclick='loops3()'>Submit</button><br><br> Write factorial of input<br>
  <input type='text' id='input4' placeholder='enter number'><br>
  <button type='submit' onclick='loops4()'>Submit</button><br><br>
  <button type='button' onclick='loops5()'>Display Array</button>
</form>
<div id='showN'></div>
```

Comment: When you click a button in a form, the form submits and refreshes the page.

Comment: Specifically, the `type="submit"` one does (or any without a `type`, since `submit` is the default). Your `type="button"` one won't.

Comment: try `onclick='loops1();return false;'`

Comment: Or just move the button elements after the form....

Comment: Since you're not actually using the `<form>` element for anything, you can just get rid of it and keep its contents.

Comment: Consistency is a Good Thing `<button type='button' onclick='loops2()'>Loop2</button>`

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is, because you placed everything in a form, and your buttons all have a "submit" type, the browser is trying to "submit" your form. Because you don't have a target or method set, it's effectively just refreshing the page.

```html
  Write all numbers between 0 and input<br>
  <input type='text' id='input1' placeholder='enter number'><br>
  <button onclick='loops1()'>Submit</button><br><br> Write sum of numbers 1 to input<br>
  <input type='text' id='input2' placeholder='enter number'><br>
  <button onclick='loops2()'>Submit</button><br><br> Write sum of even numbers from 1 to input<br>
  <input type='text' id='input3' placeholder='enter number'><br>
  <button onclick='loops3()'>Submit</button><br><br> Write factorial of input<br>
  <input type='text' id='input4' placeholder='enter number'><br>
  <button onclick='loops4()'>Submit</button><br><br>
  <button onclick='loops5()'>Display Array</button>
```

Without the form tags should give you the result you want.

Comment: Or just have `<button type='button' onclick='loops2()'>Loop2</button>` and be consistent